# YQL - how to sign request by custom ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, yql

I have very simple jQuery application quering YQL with

```
SELECT title, href FROM digg.search.search WHERE query="cats" LIMIT 5
```

I'm logging each query to simple ul-li list, where I'm indicating state of ajax request (ajax-loader, ok, error). After the request is finished, I want to change `CSS class` of appropriate li-element from `"loading"` to `"ok"`/`"err"` respectively.

But to identify correct li-element, I must somehow find it by some unique ID. I mark li-element by `data-` attribute before AJAX call like this:

```
var rqid = uniqId();
$searchLogger.append('<li class="loading" data-rqid="'+ rqid +'"><a href="#">' + q + '</a></li>');
$.ajax({
    url     : 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
    type    : 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data    : {
        callback : '',
        format   : 'json',
        env      : 'store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys',
        q        : 'SELECT title, href FROM digg.search.search WHERE query="' + q + '" LIMIT 5'
    }
```

In success callback I need to reference according li element. I cannot reuse `rqid` variable, cos it can be rewriten by other request while the first is still waiting for response.

```
success: function(data) {
    $searchLogger.find('[data-rqid="' + idOfThisRequest + '"]')
        .removeClass('loading')
        .removeClass('error')
        .addClass('ok');

    ... // other code
}
```

Is there any option to YQL request, to  "sign" request by my `rqid`, and to fetch that ID in callback?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any option in YQL to add such a unique ID to the query that would be returned in the callback.

Since you are using jQuery, you might be able to do something as described here in the jQuery forums: [Uniquely identifying ajax requests / responses](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/uniquely-identifying-ajax-requests-responses). Basically they are adding to the XHR request a unique identifier which you can read in the callback function.